# How do I find the element at an index position in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array list, I know the position of the element I want to return. For example:

```
String[] array = {"a","b","c"}
```

I want to return the element in position 1. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: You say you have an "array list" - do you mean `ArrayList` or just an array? Also, did you really mean to use the "processing" tag which refers to another programming language called "processing" that's nothing to do with Java?

Comment: Did you try something and get a result you didn't understand?

Comment: Yes it's an ArrayList and I've tried the array.get() method but it just freezes my program

Comment: `get()` wouldn't cause your program to freeze (99% sure); something else must be wrong.  Show us the entire code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just do: `array[0]`
Don't forget arrays position start from 0, so in this case position 1 would be 0.

```
array [0] = 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of array you can get the element at position 'index' as follows:

```
int index = 0;
String value = array[index];
```

If it is an ArrayList, you can get the element at position 'index' as follows:

```
 int index = 0;
 String value = arryList.get(index);
```

Comment: With the .get method I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 48, Size: 6` and my software freezes saying "Not Responding"

Comment: @dsec35 the error message is telling you that you are calling `.get(48)`. This is probably because you did `.get('0')` instead of `.get(0)`. The character '0' has a Unicode value of 48, hence calling `.get('0')` is like calling `.get(48)`. You need to call `.get(0)` instead.

Comment: As @KlitosKyriacou mentioned, you are trying to access with character '0' which is being cast to integer 48(Unicode value). As your ArrayList size is less than 48, it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. The get method os ArrayList accepts an integer as a parameter. Hence you should use `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, for example:

`String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"}` and you want to get the element with index. Do something like this:

```
array[0] -> first element
array[1] -> second element
```

If you have an arraylist, for example:

```
List<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
letters.add("a");
letters.add("b");
```

You can get the first element by using
`letters.get(0);`